# Adding a device to a subnet that can not have the local ip address changed

Tags: networking, home-networking, subnet, vlan

My subnet is 192.168.99.x and there are 45 devices connected to it with static ip's assigned. I want to add a device to the network but unfortunately the ip address is fixed at 192.168.1.2 ... there's no way to change it. Is there any way to link in the extra device somehow? I have an extra router (running Tomato) that I can use if needed, but I've never done any type of linking subnets using VLAN or anything like that.

My ideal solution would be the ability to basically treat 192.168.99.x and 192.168.1.x as a single subnet so that any device on one subnet could talk to any device on the other.

The extra router (Asus RTN16 running Tomato by Shibby) is currently on 192.168.99.102 and uses the Gateway at 192.168.99.1. The extra router is there because the main router (Linksys LRT224) doesn't have WiFi.

I normally would just try to work through setting static forwards and stuff, but because I don't really know what I'm doing there, and the fact that I'm 1500 miles from the router and can only access it remotely, I thought I should ask for some help before I break something that would require a plane trip to reset.

Comment: You need to provide us more information about the device you are unable to configure it's ip address. "My ideal solution would be the ability to basically treat 192.168.99.x and 192.168.1.x as a single subnet so that any device on one subnet could talk to any device on the other." - While it is possible to get devices in different subnets to communicate with one another you won't be able to treat them as a single subnet for obvious reasons (they are not the same subnet).

Comment: Well, yes, I realize that they can't literally be treated as one subnet. But I mostly just want to be able to access (ping, http, etc...) between the two subnets. For example, I could "ping 192.168.99.5" from 192.168.1.73 and get valid responses. Or open a webpage on 192.168.1.56 from 192.168.99.32. Just full communication between the two subnets.

Comment: You would have to connect a router to your 192.168.1.x subnet and assigned it an ip address from the 192.168.1.x subnet, then configure it to assigned ip addresses to any device connected to it an ip address from the 192.168.99.x subnet in order to do that.

Comment: Ok, so this means that I should change the local ip on the Asus to 192.168.1.1, allow it to handle ip's through DHCP and assign ip's to the 192.168.99.x range? If that's the case, how do I connect to the Asus once the local ip is configured to the .1 range when the machine I am remoting into is on .99?

Answer (score 0):

Most routers do NAT that is what you want.

1. You assign the routers main WAN IP to 192.168.99.100 (for example).
2. Then setup the computers behind the NAT (LAN) to 192.168.1.1
3. Plug device into NATed router.

Then setup port forwarding for all the ports you need.

In fact that is how almost all ISP modems, switcher, or routers work now.  I get 1 IP from my ISP and NAT the rest to multiple different subnets.

Comment: That's basically how I have it set up now. The main router is on 192.168.99.1, 45-50 other machines are on 192.168.99.x. There is one extra router (providing WiFi) which is currently also on 192.168.99.x. The only problem is the one new device which is set to 192.168.1.2 and cannot be changed. So, rather than changing all other devices over to 192.168.1.x, I'd prefer to bridge 192.168.1.x and 192.168.99.x, if at all possible.

Comment: The main router (Linksys LRT224) is basically the gateway to all other devices. The new device is connected by ethernet to the switch portion on the Asus RTN16 (running Tomato by Shibby). Trying to "ping 192.168.1.2" returns nothing but timeouts. Before I left the site, I could connect to the new device just fine when I set my computers ip address to the same 192.168.1.x range. I also verified that the ip address 192.168.1.2 is correct, so I know that's not the problem.

Comment: You will have to setup port forwarding to get it to work.  ping uses icmp so I am not sure if you can forward that, as many routers just offer tcp and udp forwarding.  After you forward all the ports you need you should be able to connect on a forwarded port.

Comment: I'm not sure how port forwarding would do anything when they are on different subnets. I guess an http redirect would work for that particular case, if I were able to get to the isolated machine, which I can't. So that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: port forwarding forward traffic from 192.168.99.100 to 192.168.1.2 or whatever IP you designate.